# 3 models which I have built result in the exact same result, how can it be?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, roc

I have 3 models which I have built,
I have used the following libraries:

```
library(rpart)
library(caTools)
library(rpart.plot)
library(stats)
library(neuralnet)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(ROCR)
library(AUC)
```

Those 3 models are: Decision tree, Logistic regression and a simple NN.
for some reason all models gives me the **same exact results** how can it be??

All columns of the data are categorical so I made sure all be converted to factor:

### Converting to factors:

```
for (column in colnames(data)){
  data[,column] <- as.factor(as.numeric(data[ ,column]))
}
```

### **Decision tree:**

```
tree_model <- rpart(MAX_SEV_IR ~ .,data = training, method="class")
rpart.plot(tree_model)
# predictions
# For 400 rows we get 400 predictions
y_pred_testing_model1 = predict(tree_model, newdata = x_testing, type = "class") 

# confusion_matrix_decision_tree <- table(testing$MAX_SEV_IR, y_pred_testing)
y_pred_testing_tree <- as.factor(y_pred_testing_model1)

model1_tree <- caret::confusionMatrix(y_pred_testing_tree, y_testing)
print(paste0("The Accuracy of the decision tree is: ", model1_tree$overall["Accuracy"]))

r <- roc(y_pred_testing_model1,y_testing )
auc(r)
plot(r)
```

### **Logistic Regression**

```
logistic_model <- glm(formula =  MAX_SEV_IR ~ .,
                      data = training , 
                      family = "binomial")


Predict_logistic <- predict(logistic_model, x_testing, type = "response")
# confusion_matrix_logistic <- table(testing$MAX_SEV_IR, Predict_logistic)
y_pred_testing_logistic <- as.numeric(ifelse(Predict_logistic>0.5, 1, 0))
y_pred_testing_logistic <- as.factor(y_pred_testing_logistic)
model2_logistic <- caret::confusionMatrix(y_pred_testing_logistic, y_testing)
print(paste0("The Accuracy of the Logistic Model is: ", model2_logistic$overall["Accuracy"]))


r <- roc(y_pred_testing_logistic,y_testing)
auc(r)
plot(r)
```

### **Neural Network:**

```
set.seed(1)
nn <- neuralnet( MAX_SEV_IR ~ .,
                data = training,
                linear.output = F,
                rep=5,
                hidden = 3)

plot(nn, rep="best")
# predict small example
pred <- predict(nn, x_testing)

y_pred_testing_nn <- as.numeric(ifelse(pred>0.5, 1, 0))
y_pred_testing_nn <- as.factor(y_pred_testing_nn)

model3_nn <- caret::confusionMatrix(y_pred_testing_nn , y_testing)
print(paste0("The Accuracy of the Neural Network Model is: ", model3_nn$overall["Accuracy"]))

r <- roc(y_pred_testing,y_testing)
auc(r)
plot(r)
```

Can somebody please point out what is done wrong,
am I missing something?

Thank you sincerely!

Comment: clear all variables and run your codes independently again. Probably you use the same vars, e.g. in nn you use `y_pred_testing` instead of `y_pred_testing_nn` I suppose.

Comment: Thank you @gunes, I  have done it, but still the same result :/, is there any other suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you could also share your updated code and plots?

Comment: Without looking at the code, there may be data that are so clear and unambiguous (particularly small datasets) that all these methods give the same results. Are you sure this is wrong?

Comment: Although this looks like a coding question, one should know about how ROC works and what to input to it, so I disagree the closing reason of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inputting binary classification results (1 or 0) to auc and roc calculations. Instead, these functions require non-thresholded outputs. Because, roc curve is plotted by changing a threshold and applying it to the raw model outputs. So, you should input `pred` in neural net, `Predict_logistic` in logreg and for the decision tree you need to get probability outputs instead of binary classification results.